# Rational Roots of a Polynomial on C[X]

Tags: polynomials

I am stuck with this problem, since I cannot apply the known theorems.

Determine all the possible polynomials of the type $X^4 + iX^3 + 2X^2+ aiX + b$ with $a,b$ integers and $(a:b) = 1$, so that they have at least one rational root.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** $\,\ a,b,x\in \Bbb Q,\ \ {-}(x^3\!+ax)\,i\, =\, x^4+2x^2+b \in \Bbb Q\,$ implies both sides $= 0.$

Comment: Right, I get from both equations that b = -a^2 + 2a.
I'm not sure if that is correct, and then I don't know how to "force" it to have at least one rational root.

Comment: So if $\,x\ne 0\,$ then $\,x^2+a=0\,$ and the rhs $\,= (x^2+a)(x^2+2-a) = 0\,$ Can you take it from there?

Comment: When I divide the polynomial by $(x^2 + a)$ I get that the original polynomial $F(x) = (x^2 + a)(x^2 + ix + 2 - a)$. 

And b should be equal to $-a^2+2a$. Am I doing something wrong in the process?

Comment: @John Note $\,a\mid b.\,$ But $\,(a,b) = 1\,$ so $\,a =\,\ldots$

Comment: ... So $|a| = 1 \Rightarrow (a,b) = (1,1) \lor (a,b) = (-1,-3)$ (since $b= -a^2 + 2a$)  
If $(a,b) = (1,1) \Rightarrow F_1(X) = (X^2+1)(X^2+iX+1)$  

And if $(a,b) = (-1,-3) \Rightarrow F_2(X) = (X^2-1)(X^2+iX+5)$  

But from the first term you can see that $F_1$ doesn't have a root in $\Bbb Q$. So the only valid pair is $(a,b) = (-1,-3)$.  
  
So there is only one possible F(X), being: $F(X) = X^4 + iX^3 + 2X^2 - iX -3$

Comment: @John There are also the valid pairs $(a,b)=(\pm 1,0)$ for which $X=0$ is a root, and $\gcd(a,b)=1.$

Comment: You're right. Thank you very much Bill and coffeemath!